# Autofac: AddAuthentication inside a module in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, autofac-module

I would like to know how to register the authentication service (e.g. `AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer()`) inside a module which dwells on its own assembly.

I tried using the `builder.Populate(services)` but I am confused of whether is OK since AutoFac documentation https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#startup-class
calls not to use it.

Comment: This is _basically_ the same question [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360096/how-to-register-healthcheck-in-autofac-module/75369355#75369355) - where the linked question asks how to use `AddHealthCheck`, this question asks how to use `AddAuthentication`. Short answer: Don't do that.